# Reuse component in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem when trying to reuse a component in React. I have 3 components,

`BookList` received a list of books from `props` and render it on the screen.

The `Home` component is the page to display the list of books and it's the parent of the `BookList` component.

And the last one is the `SearchFilter` component, users can enter search, filter pattern.

I'm trying to reuse the `BookList` component. So when people do search and filter function. It will change the list of book and pass the new booklist props to `BookList` component to re-render

So it makes sense for me to make `BookList` is a child component of both `Home` and `SearchFilter` component and both pass `booklist` props to its child. But how react know which `booklist` props from the parent components it will take into account to render on screen?

Does anyone know the correct pattern for this problem of reuse component for the list page and filter page in React?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you post code?  Also, what have you tried?  `setState()` seems to be what you should be trying.  Probably `setState({somebooks})` and then have a foreach on this.state's books in `render()`?

Answer (score 0):

> But how react know which booklist props from the parent components it will take into account to render on screen?

It depends on how you handle the search filter. For example if you have a state of books and you want to display a list of books that start with the letter 'A', you would need a function that handles this filter. Inside that function, you filter and update the state of the book list with setState() and pass it as a prop to the BookList component.

For example filterFunction() is a function that filters the book list array:

```
<input type="search" onsearch="filterFunction()">
<BookList bookList={this.state.bookList} />
```

Once the state is updated it automatically renders the updated `this.state.bookList` array.

You can build it from scratch but there are libraries you can use such as [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/) specifically [material-table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#material-table) that does it for you.